# How to get the value of a attribute of an element in xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, attributes, element

I'm tring to get the color and the image of this code:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="logsss_event_cl itemAttr current " title="MULTI" data- 
 value="MULTI" data-logsss-const-value="{'x': 'change_color'}"><img 
 src="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2020/12/24thumb- 
 img/1608776712993433956.jpg?im_scale=h34_1x"></a>

 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="logsss_event_cl itemAttr  " title="LIGHT PINK" data-value="LIGHT 
 PINK" data-logsss-const-value="{'x': 'change_color'}"><img 
 src="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2021/04/08thumb- 
 img/1617901013166741553.jpg?im_scale=h34_1x"></a>
```

Both of these look the same except in the class one ends in current.

My problem is I do not know how to get just the value of an element.

I've tried:

```
 color1a= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-attr-0"]/a[1]').text

 color1a= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='logsss_event_cl itemAttr 
 current']").get_Attribute("data-value").text

 tumb1= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-attr-0"]/a[2]/img').text
```

Comment: when you say image is it src that you want to extract and what do you mean by color ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the link use (first element):

```
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".logsss_event_cl.itemAttr.current>img").get_attribute("src")
```

Second link:

```
link2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".logsss_event_cl.itemAttr:nth-of-type(2)>img").get_attribute("src")
```

To get the color attribute of the second element:

```
color = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".logsss_event_cl.itemAttr:nth-of-type(2)").get_attribute("data-value")
```

`.` is for class names. `>` - direct child. It is easier than xpath. You do not need to use `.text`.

If you want to use xpath: `//*[@class='logsss_event_cl itemAttr current ']/img` would be sufficient.
If the color of the first element is **MULTI**, than you need attribute named `value`, not `data-value`.

Comment: Thanks that worked for the color.  How do I get the tumb?

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept upvote if the question is solved. What about link? I've changed attribute name in the answer. It should be src, not img.

Comment: Check updated answer for both links

Comment: Good explanation @vitaliis